# Flutter - Transform flutter bloc event call only first event

Tags: flutter, bloc

How can I call only first event in my bloc?

```
@override
  Stream<Transition< GithubSearchEvent, GithubSearchState >> transformEvents(
      Stream< GithubSearchEvent > events, transitionFn) {
    return events
        .debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 300))
        .switchMap((transitionFn));
  }
```

Comment: what you mean by "call only first event "?

Comment: in my bloc I call many events, like succesEvent, failEvent, and want get only first event, 
if in my bloc events call like this order succesEvent, failEvent, etc... , I want call only succesEvent

Comment: yes I call this events